# Flask redirect doesn't actually take user to a different page

Tags: python, flask

'main' is just my homepage and '/' is the url. For some reason, I can't get signUp to return back to the homepage after finishing.

I can also confirm 'here' and 'Registered' get printed. Also, in my terminal, i get

127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2018 23:13:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Which means it SHOULD be going to home, because I get the same line when I just click the home link on the page through html. Clicking the link redirects too. It also is the same path '/', so I'm not sure why it works with html but not with flask when I know the redirect gets acknowledged.

What happens with the flask is it just stays on the signup page. Nothing else, no errors thrown. Just sits there.

I was even able to do redirect('main', code=307) and it actually ran code on the main page. So why wouldn't this simple redirect render Senty.html and take the user to the page?

```
@app.route("/")
def main():
   return render_template('Senty.html')

@app.route('/signUp',methods=['POST','GET'])
def signUp():
    # still need to create signup class and transfer below code to new file
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cur = conn.cursor()

   try:
        _name = request.form['inputName']
         _email = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']

        # validate the received values
        if _name and _email and _password:

            cur.callproc('sp_createUser',(_name,_email,_password,))
            print ("Registered")
            data = cur.fetchall()

            conn.commit()
            json.dumps({'message':'User created successfully !'})
            print('here')
            return redirect(url_for('main'))

    #else:
         #return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

    #except Exception as e:
        #return json.dumps({'error':str(e)})

    finally:
        cur.close() 
        conn.close()
        return redirect(url_for('main'))
```

I'm not sure where to go. I feel like I've tried everything. Here is also the HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Senty App</h1>
      <form method="POST">
        <label for="inputName" class="sr-only">Name</label>
        <input type="name" name="inputName" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

        <button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button">Sign up</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's totally possible that your function throws an error before the `try` and then never gets to the finally? It is also possible that some of the stuff you're doing in `finally` errors and then you never get to the redirect. Your best bet is to isolate things and keep trying from a minimal base case.

Comment: @Alper At one point I put 'return redirect(url_for('main'))' at the top of the function and commented everything out and it still didn't take me to the home page. I did not write this, a teammate did. Are there any problems you could think of with the methods post and get?

Comment: Then reduce out the `url_for` function and make it a hard URL?

Comment: Just to be sure, have you imported redirect and url_for  `from flask import url_for, redirect`